# Selenium Python Get Img SRC Returns Actual Image Data

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am working with Selenium in Python and using Firefox web driver.

I am trying to get the SRC of an image. When I first request the SRC I get the actual image data, not the SRC

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ ...
```

If I run the exact same code a second time I will get the SRC

```
example.jpg
```

Here is my code

```
fireFoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
fireFoxOptions.set_headless()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=fireFoxOptions)

element = browser.find_element(By.ID , "idOfImageHere" )
imageUrl = element.get_attribute("src")
print("image src: " + imageUrl)
```

Not sure why the image data is being returned on the first time the code is ran, and then the src in the second run. It almost seems that once the image is cached then it can get the src or something like that.

Any suggestions on how to prevent the image data from being returned, just the src link?

Thanks

Comment: the src must be changing.. it's possible that there is javascript which re-writes the src attribute.  (maybe it loads a low-res version or placeholder first)

Comment: that could be possible. I am scraping from amazon so I assume they have some fancy code running. That being said, I don't really care if I get the SRC of the low res image, I just don't want the image data

Comment: you could use a WebDriverWait to wait for the SRC to endWith ".jpg" (or .gif, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/) website elements are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled elements so to extract the `src` attribute of any element, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "idOfImageHere"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='idOfImageHere]"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#idOfImageHere"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This is very interesting. I will try it out and get back to you. Thanks.